# Handshake Exception saying 'TLSV1_ALERT_NO_APPLICATION_PROTOCOL(tls_record.cc:594))' in flutter app integrating giphy rest api

Tags: flutter, http, https, dio, giphy-api

I am integrating giphy api in one of my flutter project but it is resulting with exception 'TLSV1_ALERT_NO_APPLICATION_PROTOCOL(tls_record.cc:594))'.

I created another flutter project with almost same flutter sdk and http client version. But here is no problem. Its weird. Does anyone know why this happens ?